# Pandas - Change Key Value Columns to Keyed Row

Tags: pandas

I have data that I need to gather sum and unique count statistics on.  the rough format of the data is below coming in as CSV:

```
Customer     PartType        2011        2012       2013
A            widget_b        1000        10000      20000
B            widget_a        1           1000       5000
....
```

I need to be able to aggregate this table by customer (without PartType) and do a sum and count of customers in size bins by YEAR, as well as do the same exercise counting customers by PART_TYPE by year.

A few questions:

1) is there an easy way of using pandas to make a data frame that looks like:

```
Customer     PartType    Year     value
A            widget_b    2011     1000
A            widget_b    2012     10000
....
```

I think I can do this with a pandas.pivot_table however the result is an odd datatype that groupby can't handle easily.

2) is there an easy way of generating sum and count by year inside of customer size buckets?  I've used the pd.cut inside the groupby method and it only generates the sum or count for one year at a time so when you print the other years results they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you're looking to [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt):

```
melted = pd.melt(df, ["Customer", "PartType"])
melted.rename(columns={"variable": "Year"}, inplace=True)
melted = melted.sort("Customer").reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

Starting from a slightly more interesting `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df
  Customer  PartType  2011   2012   2013
0        A  widget_b  1000  10000  20000
1        B  widget_a     1   1000   5000
2        B  widget_c   111    222    333
```

We use `pd.melt` to unpivot the frame:

```
>>> melted = pd.melt(df, ["Customer", "PartType"])
>>> melted
  Customer  PartType variable  value
0        A  widget_b     2011   1000
1        B  widget_a     2011      1
2        B  widget_c     2011    111
3        A  widget_b     2012  10000
4        B  widget_a     2012   1000
5        B  widget_c     2012    222
6        A  widget_b     2013  20000
7        B  widget_a     2013   5000
8        B  widget_c     2013    333
```

This has the boring name `"variable"`, though, and it's not in the order we want.  That's easy enough to fix:

```
>>> melted.rename(columns={"variable": "Year"}, inplace=True)
>>> melted = melted.sort("Customer").reset_index(drop=True)
>>> melted
  Customer  PartType  Year  value
0        A  widget_b  2013  20000
1        A  widget_b  2012  10000
2        A  widget_b  2011   1000
3        B  widget_a  2012   1000
4        B  widget_c  2012    222
5        B  widget_a  2013   5000
6        B  widget_c  2013    333
7        B  widget_a  2011      1
8        B  widget_c  2011    111
```

I'm not sure I follow exactly what aggregation you want, but you should be able to apply `groupby` however you like.  For example:

```
>>> melted.groupby(["Customer", "Year"]).sum()
               value
Customer Year       
A        2011   1000
         2012  10000
         2013  20000
B        2011    112
         2012   1222
         2013   5333
```